# Export WFS Features as Shapefile giving Error number: (8, '') using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, wfs

I am new to PyQGIS and trying to export a WFS Feature as a Shapefile called Test.shp.

```
uri = r"https://www.geoportal.rlp.de/mapbender/php/wfs.php?INSPIRE=1&FEATURETYPE_ID=2939&VERSION=2.0.0"
outputPath = 'C://Users//xxx//PyQGIS//Test.shp'

lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Temp", "WFS")

res=QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')

if res != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print ("Error number:", res, "and", QgsVectorFileWriter.WriterError())
else:
    print ("WFS saved!")
```

res is giving me the Error code 8 without any details.

```
Error number: (8, '') and 0
```

I read the documentation of QgsVectorFileWriter and alle the other duplicates on exchange but couldn't find any information why my code isn't working.

Comment: step 1: does it work on the command line with `ogr2ogr`? step 2: does the URL work in the browser? step 3: is the returned data valid for a shapefile

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. 
1) 'ogr2ogr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Python -m pip show gdal works...
2) yes, even QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(tempWFS) for creating a vector layer works
3) I don't know. How can i find out?

Comment: numbers at the attribute names, geometry not called `the_geom`, mixed geometry types

Comment: sorry, I don't understand anything. As I mentioned I'm a newbie but however, I solved the problem

Comment: The service URL is: `http://map1.sgdnord.rlp.de/kartendienste_rok/mod_ogc/wfs_getmap.php?mapfile=rrop_mw_2017&`

Comment: @nmtoken I can see that this URL provides all feature at once. With my answer I can only export the layer with the typename='ms:mw_161208_03_vr_landwirtschaft. Is there a possibility to download all the layers at once? And maybe name them "typename".shp?

Comment: You can't get all features types in one GetFeature request

Comment: ok I understand. So in the best case you find a regularity in the typenames and implement this in your python code to "automatically" download all files? Isnt there a way to get all typenames of "http://map1.sgdnord.rlp.de/kartendienste_rok/mod_ogc/wfs_getmap.php?mapfile=rrop_mw_2017&" to create a python list of them? Thank you very much so far!

Comment: I will use "&request=GetCapabilities" to scrape out all typnames. Maybe you know a more elegant action.

Comment: from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
    
wfs = WebFeatureService(url='https://geodatendienste-landesplanung-hessen.de/geoserver/nordhessen/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities', version='2.0.0')
Liste=list(wfs.contents)
print(Liste)

Comment: A GetCapabilities request/response is the designed mechanism to get the typenames from any WFS service; DescribeFeatureType gives you more information, and GetFeature fetches the data

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I copied the "source" from the layer-properties inside QGIS and used it as my URL and it worked.

```
uri=r"pagingEnabled='true'preferCoordinatesForWfsT11='false'restrictToRequestBBOX='1'srsname='EPSG:25832'typename='ms:mw_161208_03_vr_landwirtschaft'url='https://www.geoportal.rlp.de/mapbender/php/wfs.phpINSPIRE=1&FEATURETYPE_ID=2935'url='https://www.geoportal.rlp.de/mapbender/php/wfs.phpINSPIRE=1&FEATURETYPE_ID=2935&VERSION=2.0.0' version='auto'"
outputPath = 'C:/Users/xxx/PyQGIS/Test.shp'

lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Temp", "WFS")

res=QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')

if res != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print ("Error number:", res, "and", QgsVectorFileWriter.WriterError())
else:
    print ("WFS saved!")
```

I still get the `Error number: (0, '') and 0` but maybe that's a good sign :)

EDIT:

The code doesn't work in the case it has to replace the test.shp file. So please delete the files after every try.